# Joining Broken lines and Dotted lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect the broken lines that are highlighted in red color and the dotted lines that are highlighted in yellow color.

Till now, I have tried various methods such as morphological operations, Probabilistic Hough transform, Hough transform, and Contour detection, but did not get successful results.

Because of the big dots inside the red region, that common line connecting the curved shapes are being detected as multiple lines. Also, results from above mentioned methods were not able to join the dotted lines inside the yellow region.

My objective is to detect and draw a line over the big line inside the red region and also to detect and convert the dotted lines into a straight horizontal or vertical line.

Can anyone provide a solution to my problem statement?

[image]

Comment: Are you scanning an image to determine where the dots are or are you scanning the data file that generates this image?

Comment: scanning the image to find where the dots are.

Comment: So in the image above do you find the 14 dots or do  you not find anything at all or do you find things that are not dots

Comment: I want to find the lines connecting the dots and merge all those lines if the dots are collinear.